# Compiling a list of audio + video players (flash / javascript / otehr) that I can embed into a website

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, audio

I'm compiling a list of audio + video players (flash / javascript / other) that I can embed into a website.

- flowplayer: http://flowplayer.org/
- jw player:
  http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/
- premium beat:
  http://www.premiumbeat.com/flash_resources/free_flash_music_player/
- xspf web player:
  http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/
- yahoo media player:
  http://mediaplayer.yahoo.com/
- f4player: http://f4player.org/
- VideoJS: http://videojs.com/

any popular ones I'm missing?  (anyone know if I can skin / customize any of them to operate similar to the Windows vista volume control?)

Comment: Can you change the link on your post if possible because now, f4Player is on my website under http://gokercebeci.com/dev/f4player

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are open source, so you could skin them however you want:

Flash (AS3):
http://f4player.org/

HTML5:
http://videojs.com/

Comment: Can you change the link on your post if possible because now, f4Player is on my website under http://gokercebeci.com/dev/f4player

Answer (score 0):

Wimpy Player has a nice new HTML 5-based audio player:
[www.wimpyplayer.com](http://www.wimpyplayer.com)

The skin designer is pretty sweet:
[www.wimpyplayer.com/skinmachine](http://www.wimpyplayer.com/skinmachine)

The older 100% Flash players are now free on their dot NET site [www.wimpyplayer.NET](http://www.wimpyplayer.net)